# Which SQL has a better performance?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 sql statements as below. They can retrieve the same dataset. As I tested, it seems  SQL2 always has a better performance. And I explained both statements. They have the same execution plan.

Can anyone help to explain if it is performance impacting when using subquery here?
And how can we use subquery to do sql tuning?

Thanks very much!

```
--SQL 1
SELECT ADDRRF.ENTITYKEYID,
    ADDRESS1,
    ADDRESS2
FROM WODS_STG.BLIS_ADDRESSREFERENCE ADDRRF
LEFT JOIN WODS_STG.BLIS_ADDRESS ADDR
    ON ADDRRF.ADDRESSID = ADDR.ADDRESSID
WHERE ADDRRF.ADDRESSTYPEID = 10
    AND ADDRRF.ENTITYID = 3;

--SQL 2
SELECT ADDRRF.ENTITYKEYID,
    ADDRESS1,
    ADDRESS2
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM WODS_STG.BLIS_ADDRESSREFERENCE
    WHERE ADDRESSTYPEID = 10
        AND ENTITYID = 3
    ) ADDRRF
LEFT JOIN WODS_STG.BLIS_ADDRESS ADDR
    ON ADDRRF.ADDRESSID = ADDR.ADDRESSID;
```

Comment: Please show us the execution plan. You can also use `set autotrace traceonly` in SQL*Plus to see more details about the execution of the statements (see the manual for details)

Comment: I guess that the second query has a better performance as first you filtre the result and then you left join them.

Comment: @CiucaS: It shall not have an impact. Oracle does a load of transformations internally when constructing execution plans. The two queries are, as far as I can see, functionally identical.

Sasfan, post both execution plans into your question and don't strip away the "predicates" section from the plans. Thanks.

Comment: you were going to type the word `FROM` instead of the word "frin", weren't you? I agree with @a_horse_with_no_name we need to see explain plans of these queries, but before that don't forget to gather statistics `DBMS_STATS.gather_schema_stats(...`

Answer (score 2):

The second query can be faster because it reads data from the SGA area that was cached by the first query. In different words, the first query use hard parse and the second use soft parse, because they have the same execution plan. Try to run several times both of them to find out if the second query is still faster.

Comment: Caching definitely could be a reason for the perceived difference.  But I doubt soft and hard parsing are relevant; a hard parse happens for even slightly different text, it doesn't matter if the execution plan is the same.

Comment: You totally right, but this is only idea I have without the explanation plans for the queries.

Answer (score 0):

SQL 1 :

Here, sql engine first joins the tables, BLIS_ADDRESSREFERENCE and BLIS_ADDRESS, and then applies the WHERE predicates to filter the records.

SQL 2 :

Here, sql engine first filter the records from table BLIS_ADDRESSREFERENCE and then joins with the BLIS_ADDRESS table. I guess SQL 2 is faster since the filter records from BLIS_ADDRESSREFERENCE are smaller than BLIS_ADDRESS.

Comment: It is unlikely that an Oracle SQL statement is executed in the same order it is written.  In this case, [simple view merging](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/optimizer_transformations_view_merging_part_1) will almost certainly make these two queries run the same way.

Comment: True, I wrote what I guessed. There are many factors determines the query plan. To understand what really happens behind the query execution, I must use dbms_xplan.display_cursor() to find out. [https://hourim.wordpress.com/2011/12/29/getting-explain-plan/](https://hourim.wordpress.com/2011/12/29/getting-explain-plan/)

Comment: Oracle parses query and then selects the best plan based on the statistics. Your conclusion would have been true, if the author specified some hints about join order and etc.